# InvalidOperationException in PhotoCaptureDevice in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera

When I call await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(..) in windows phone 8 camera app throws InvalidOperationException.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object. at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   JPMC.Controls.CaptureTaskLauncher.d_6.MoveNext() --- End of stack
>   trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b_0(Object
>   state)}

but one more thing is whenever I run camera test first time it will work perfectly i.e PhotoCaptureDevice initialized properly but when I will come back from another page to Camera test it will give error mentioned above.
So,anyone can help me to figure out this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried releasing the resources before leaving the page, using  PhotoCaptureDevice.Close() and Dispose() ?

Comment: yes,I have tried it, but no use.after that also throws an exception.

Comment: Then you're going to need to show a bit more code (or should I say - at least some code) to show how your initializing the PhotoCaptureDevice etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static PhotoCaptureDevice d = null;
        public static async Task<bool> InitializeCamera(CameraSensorLocation sensorLocation)
        {
            bool catchValue = true;
            try
            {
                Windows.Foundation.Size initialResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
                Windows.Foundation.Size previewResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
                Windows.Foundation.Size captureResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
                d = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(sensorLocation, initialResolution);
                await d.SetPreviewResolutionAsync(previewResolution);
                await d.SetCaptureResolutionAsync(captureResolution);               
                d.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.PlayShutterSoundOnCapture, true);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();                
                CameraCaptureSequence sequence = d.CreateCaptureSequence(1);
                sequence.Frames[0].CaptureStream = stream.AsOutputStream();
                await d.PrepareCaptureSequenceAsync(sequence);                
                await sequence.StartCaptureAsync();                            
                if (stream.Length > 0)
                {
                    d.Dispose();
                    d = null;
                    stream.Dispose();
                    stream = null;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    d.Dispose();
                    d = null;
                    stream.Dispose();
                    stream = null;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                catchValue = false;
            }
            if (!catchValue)
            {
                Windows.Foundation.Size initialResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
                Windows.Foundation.Size previewResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
                Windows.Foundation.Size captureResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);

                 d = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(sensorLocation,initialResolution);

                await d.SetPreviewResolutionAsync(previewResolution);
                await d.SetCaptureResolutionAsync(captureResolution);

                d.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.PlayShutterSoundOnCapture, true);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                CameraCaptureSequence sequence = d.CreateCaptureSequence(1);
                sequence.Frames[0].CaptureStream = stream.AsOutputStream();
                await d.PrepareCaptureSequenceAsync(sequence);

                await sequence.StartCaptureAsync();

                if (stream.Length > 0)
                {
                    d.Dispose();
                    d = null;
                    stream.Dispose();
                    stream = null;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    d.Dispose();
                    d = null;
                    stream.Dispose();
                    stream = null;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;

        }
```